# Extracting activity from social feed widget

Tags: facebook, twitter, youtube-api, google-plus, linkedin-api

I would like to know, is there anyway for us to extract out the activites from facebook activity feed? or does facebook provide any API to do so?

Also, do twitter, linkedin, google+, youtube provide the API to do so?

I have searched around the social developer documentation, but couldn't find what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Call the activities edge in the graph API for that user with the `user_activities` permission:

`/USER_ID/activites`

An example for your own user account activites: [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me/activities) (make sure to "get access token" with  `user_activities` permission)

Answer (score 1):

For Google+ use the [activities.list API call](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list?userId=%252BGusClass&collection=public&_h=1&).